# Cannot See Pasted Object

Tags: objects, import

When I copy/paste an object I want from one blender file to another (which normally works) I cannot see the pasted file. I have checked to see if it is on a different layer, and it is not. I have also checked to see if the scaling is merely off, or if the perspective is clipped too close. I have changed the scale by a hundred fold, and still see nothing and have adjusted the clipping to closer, and still no dice.

Any ideas?

Images attached (I want to place the cylinder onto the rectangular surface). Photo three suggests that the object is there, but something happened to it.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: To see if objects were pasted check the 3D View header and see if geometry counters changed. My guess is that it is probably a scale issue, third screenshot shows object dimensions in microns

Comment: You were right. Astute observation! I have no idea why it got so small when imported.